# Pegar evento de seleção + movimento da seleção - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar o evento com Jquery de seleção de texto + drag.

Um exemplo do que estou dizendo, é selecionar um texto e com o botão esquerdo do mouse pressionado, movimentar o texto para os lados.

Como faço para pegar este evento. Digamos: se determinado texto estiver selecionado na div e se eu clicar em cima e mover. Como descobriria que este evento ocorreu? Pois não é apenas selecionar, é clicar e mover a seleção.

Analisando, encontrei este exemplo, onde sou impedido de selecionar o texto da div com drag. Eu sei que é possível fazer com css, mas em minha situação existem inputs, então talvez alguém queira selecionar.

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Como será que eles impediram a seleção do texto no exemplo acima?

Answer (score 2):

Selecionar o texto e clicar e arrastar usam eventos parecidos do mouse logo depende um pouco de outros fatores (interface, html, etc) para desenvolver algo 100% funcional para você. Mas segue abaixo uma possibilidade. Com esse exemplo você pode adaptar o mesmo as suas necessidades.

https://jsfiddle.net/dbeff/ktoaL0a7/1/

```js
document.onselectionchange = function() {
  var selObj = window.getSelection();
  var selRange = selObj.toString();
  console.log(selRange);
  
  document.querySelector('.selection').innerHTML = selRange;

};

$(".selection").draggable({
  cursor: "crosshair"
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="element">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde blanditiis, accusamus cum nihil laboriosam magnam animi sed provident nisi a debitis numquam sequi sit rerum dignissimos? Eveniet tempore consequuntur, aperiam.
</div>
<br>
<div class="selection">
  
</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado :D

Comment: Daniel, é quase isso que desejo  fazer. Mas não é mover o que foi selecionado e colocado em outra div. É mover o que esta selecionado. Digamos, eu seleciono o texto, ele fica com o fundo "azul". Daí se dou um clique nele e movo , eu consigo colocá-lo em "inputs". O que eu gostaria de fazer, é detectar o click e o evento move no texto selecionado. Será que existe algo para detectar que um evento ocorreu em um texto selecionado? ou terei que adicionar alguma tag antes e depois do texto selecionado e removê-la quando a seleção não existir? ATT

Comment: Você consegue fazer isso, mas visualmente não vai ficar legal. Uma solução visualmente mais amigável é fazer um elemento aparecer em cima do lugar onde você selecionou o texto com o trecho de texto selecionado e o usuário usar esse elemento para arrastar. Basicamente é pegar esse exemplo que te passei acima mas posicionando/mostrando o elemento com o texto selecionado em cima do texto selecionado.